# Use case Diagram for Pacman Arcade

Tags: uml, computer-science, software-design, use-case, use-case-diagram

Does any one know how to create use case diagram for PACMAN ARCADE game ?These are some of the features:

1. Ghost Movement & Behavior

   - when an energizer is eaten, the ghosts turn blue and flee from pac-man
   - four colors ghost pursue player
2. Energizers and power pellets and Maze generation,

   - energizers are placed at the four corners of the maze and power pellets placed throughout the maze.
3. pac-man behavior

   - movement, score, eat, death

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use-case represent actor goals, i.e. the purpose of interacting with the system. Playing is the only real goal here. So the use-case diagram would be super simple:

[image]

Use-cases are not meant to model behavior details. To model behaviors, use activity diagrams (flows of activities) and sequence diagrams (interactions between objects) or state diagrams (e.g. temporary change of states line superpowers).

And for the user interface, use non-UML techniques like wireframes or storyboards. These are meant for exactly that.

Answer (score -3):

We don't want to think about the system side. You have to only consider about the user cases only.

[image: pacman usecase]

Comment: Actually this is not a use case diagram but a functional decomposition. You should read Bittner/Spence about use case synthesis. This was an eye opener for me.